# How to get Role definition Id of an custom role in ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am currently creating an ARM template for an azure custom role and managed Identity. I can successfully create a custom role and managed Identity.Now I want to assign  that custom role to that Identity.I want to  get the role definition of the new created custom role in ARM template itself.how to the role definition ID in ARM template?

```
 "properties": {
            "roleDefinitionId": "[concat('/subscriptions/', subscription().subscriptionId, '/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/', '<Your Role definition ID>')]",
            "principalId": "<your-principal-id>"
        }
```

Comment: As fra as I knew, we cannot get it via arm template. We need to get it with powershell.

Comment: Not sure I follow - you name the roleDefinition when you create it - the GUID you use for the name is the same as you would use for the roleAssignment.  If that doesn't help, share more of your template code.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the resourceId function with the role name

```
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments",
            "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
            "name": "[guid(subscription().id, 'something')]",
            "properties": {
                "roleDefinitionId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions', guid(subscription().id, '<role definition name>'))]",
                "principalId": "<your-principal-id>"
            }
        },
```